# Use Green’s Theorem to evaluate the line integral along the given positively oriented curve. (How to set up limits of integration)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I need help on the process of setting up the limits of integration in this problem.

Use Green’s Theorem to evaluate the line integral along the given positively oriented curve.

$$\int_C (y + e^\sqrt x)\,dx + (2x + \cos y^2)\,dy,$$

where $C$ is the boundary of the region enclosed by the parabolas
$y =x^2$ and $x = y^2$.

Ok So I know how to apply greens theorem but I'm not sure how to take the limits of integration on this type of problem. I know how to find where the two parabolas intersect, at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, I got that by setting $y = x^2$ to $y = \sqrt x$ but I'm not sure what the process is in figuring out where to put them in the integrands. Can someone describe this in detail? I can't find a detailed description anywhere online.

I want to say the outer y boundaries are $0$ to $1$ and the inner x boundaries are $0$ to $y^2$ bt I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Green's Theorem states that

$$\int_CP\left(x,y\right)\,dx+Q\left(x,y\right)\,dy=\int_\Omega Q_x\left(x,y\right)-P_y\left(x,y\right)\,dA,$$

where $\Omega$ is the region enclosed by the closed curve $C$, which is oriented counterclockwise.

Therefore, your problem can be reformulated as

$$\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^{\sqrt x}\,dy\,dx.$$

I will leave the details to you.

**Edit**: Figuring out the limits of your integrals is a cal 1 problem. Just draw what the thing looks like:

[image]

I treat it as a type 1 region, and it is clear that $0\leq x\leq1$ and that $x^2\leq y\leq\sqrt x$.

Comment: ok I can do the details but my confusion was with how you decided to make the upper and lower limits of the inner integral $\sqrt x$ and $x^2$

Comment: how do you know that $x^2\leq y\leq\sqrt x$ and I guess square root of x is larger because x is between 0 and 1?

Comment: oh wait I see it its because the graph on top is root x and the bottom one is x^2

Comment: Look at the thin line: the increasing direction along the $y$-axis is *up*. Therefore, as I go from bottom to top, I first hit the red curve, which is $y=x^2$, and I then hit the blue curve, which is $y=\sqrt x$. Therefore, $x^2\leq y\leq\sqrt x$.